# Are there any implications of closing every if-block with fi in a nested if-construct?

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

As closing "fi"s for nested if-blocks are not necessary except for when delimiting else-blocks (ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15328027/1942997), I was wondering if there were any implications when doing this or if it is just a matter of style.

Example Code 1:

```
if [ condition ]; then
    echo "Not nested, condition 1 true"
    if [ other_condition ]; then
        echo "Nested, condition 2 true"
    else
        echo "Nested, condition 2 false"
    fi
fi
```

Example Code 2 (notice the missing last fi):

```
if [ condition ]; then
    echo "Not nested, condition 1 true"
    if [ other_condition ]; then
        echo "Nested, condition 2 true"
    else
        echo "Nested, condition 2 false"
fi
```

Being used to closing every if block with curly brackets from other languages, it only seems reasonable to me to keep this behavior in bash scripting. The only impact I could think of was the marginally increased file size of the script in favor of better readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged this as bash; I get "syntax error: unexpected end of file" if I don't close the inner `if`.

The referenced SO Q says:

> In bash there isn't such a thing as every `if` has to be delimited by a companion `fi` marking the end of the if block.

which could be understood two ways:

The wrong way:

> In bash there isn't such a thing as: "every `if` has to be delimited by a companion `fi` marking the end of the if block."

The right way:

> In bash there isn't such a thing [as dangling else ambiguity], as every `if` has to be delimited by a companion `fi` marking the end of the if block.

Comment: Good answer. I added a `;` to the original question, to make this more clear. Feel free to make more edits.